# Linear SVM Hyperparameter Selection

Tags: classification, support-vector-machine, multiclass-classification, cifar-10

I'm trying to train a linear SVM on the CIFAR-10 dataset and I obtained the results in the plot below for the hyper-parameter tuning (learning rate and regularization strength). It looks like the validation accuracy is identical for all the hyper-parameter combinations and I'm not sure how to interpret this given that accuracy computed on the training set is more "informative". The question is, how should this be interpreted? Should the information about the accuracy of the model on the train set be used as hint to pick the right model given that the validation accuracy is all the same? (i.e. From all the available combinations, given this data, the best combination is the one that achieves the highest accuracy on the training set since the validation accuracy doesn't seem to vary)
[image]